# What's a good approach studying opengl es 2.0?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I've been messing around with some coding and finally think I'm finally ready for the OpenGL part, then I thought again and decided that I need some guidance with how to learn/ remember OpenGL ES 2.0!

Alright, basically, I know how it works in the high level, then when I begin to type out some code....

```
I see a bunch of parameters,
I refer to some documents,
I fill in those parameters,
I see some more parameters,
I refer to more documents,
(loop)
MVC comes in,
I get completely and utterly confused!
Brain crashes.
```

I'm trying to do some simple stuff on the iPhone, I'd like to find the train of thoughts of the gurus, like some sort of check list, or order to do things, so that what I'm doing will always be clear!

Eg, something like:

```
Arrays of numbers always come before shaders
(some sets of program lines that always appear in a certain order)
```

Right now, I have a high level understanding of something like this:

http://duriansoftware.com/joe/An-intro-to-modern-OpenGL.-Chapter-1%3a-The-Graphics-Pipeline.html

What I wish I could know is what are the usual steps involve, if you were to expand all these high level understanding like tags in a website!

I tried reading some tutorials, and I'll be trying again after typing this, to attempt to absorb the common steps/ order to do this, if anyone can help speed up the process, I'll be veeeeeery very grateful! Am I asking too much? =p

Comment: This is probably better asked over at programmers.stackexchange.com as there isn't a cut-and-dried answer to this question.

Comment: As far as learning OpenGL ES 2.0, I list some resources in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4227748/19679).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596804822) tutorial book for GL on the iPhone

It's particularly useful for fairly experienced developers who are starting with GL. If you are starting at a more beginner level, it may be confusing in parts.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it's really informative after I decided to document each step in my own words, along with the objects I need to create, the big picture is clear now!